# Amavisd-new ports 10026 10024 not running

Tags: 18.04, postfix, amavisd-new

I have mail stuck in the queue and the problem according to the logs points to amavisd-new. Ports 10024 and 10026 are not running and I'm not sure whether it might have something to do with spamassassin. I installed spamassassin but if the problem does point to spamassassin I would like to disable it althought I already run this command.

> update-rc.d -f spamassassin remove

amavisd-new status

```
root@mail:/var/log# systemctl status amavisd-new.service 
● amavis.service - LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/amavis; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-06-27 12:30:24 EAT; 1h 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 29156 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/amavis stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 29162 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amavis start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: No decoder for       .jar
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: No decoder for       .lha
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: No decoder for       .lrz
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: No decoder for       .lz4
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: No decoder for       .rar
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: No decoder for       .swf
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: Using primary internal av scanner code for ClamAV-clamd
Jun 27 12:30:24 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: Found secondary av scanner ClamAV-clamscan at /usr/local/bin/clamscan
Jun 27 12:30:30 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: (!!)TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: config: no rules were found!  Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Jun 27 12:30:30 mail.domain.tld amavis[29342]: (!)_DIE: Suicide () TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: config: no rules were found!  Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
```

netstat -tlnp

```
 root@mail:/var/log# netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28799/mysqld        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10027         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1450/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23784/apache2       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1448/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1659/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1556/nrpe           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1450/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1659/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      20868/master        
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      29367/dovecot       
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      1556/nrpe           
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      29367/dovecot
```

Postconf -n

```
root@mail:/var/log# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 0
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = mail.domain.tld, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = mail.domain.tld
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 x.x.x.x/32 x.x.x.x/32 x.x.x.x/32 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
owner_request_special = no
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $sender_bcc_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
relayhost =
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/blacklist_helo
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_policy_greylist.cf
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_gids.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_uids.cf
```

master.cf

```
amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
                -o smtp_bind_address=

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       n       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks

127.0.0.1:10027 inet n - n - - smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
            -o milter_default_action=accept
        -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
        -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I re-enabled spamassassin, restarted the service and run sa-update -D -v which brought up amavisd-new. I'm wondering why it worked this time round and I'd attempted the same thing for 2 days.